# Smoothness texture map in unity

Tags: unity, textures

I shall submit a 3d asset to the Unity asset store. Their submission guidelines say,"... must include at least an albedo,normal,metallic (or specular) and smoothness texture map."

1. My query is how do I **get the smoothness map** and where do I put it ?
   There is just one slot by the smoothness slider where I put the metallic map.
2. Is it really necessary to put a smoothness texture map if I already have a metallic map attached to the material?

It's my first attempt to submit an asset to the asset store.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be covered in the [official Unity documentation on Metallic Parameters](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialParameterMetallic.html).

> By default, with no texture assigned, the Metallic and Smoothness
>   parameters are controlled by a slider each. This is enough for some
>   materials. However if your model’s surface has areas with a mixture of
>   surface types in the albedo texture, you can use a texture map to
>   control how the metallic and smoothness levels vary across the surface
>   of the material.
>   ...
>
> With a texture assigned to the Metallic parameter, both the Metallic
>   and Smoothness sliders will disappear. Instead, the Metallic levels
>   for the material are controlled by the values in the Red channel of
>   the texture, and the Smoothness levels for the material are controlled
>   by the Alpha channel of the texture. (This means the Green and Blue
>   channels are ignored). This means you have a single texture which can
>   define areas as being rough or smooth, and metallic or non-metallic ...

Based on that, if you've assigned a texture for the metallic parameter, you shouldn't need an additional texture for smoothness - one file functions as both the metallic texture map and the smoothness map simultaneously.

This was taken for the most recent version at the time it was posted (2018.2) for past versions, change the documentation version as shown here:

[image]

Comment: But even after adding metallic texture, the smoothness slider is staying. I'm also not using the latest version of Unity. Is this the reason?

Comment: @Mr.Bhaskar Possibly - what version are you using?

Comment: My version is 2017.1

Comment: @Mr.Bhaskar Hmmm, the behavior you see (slider stays after adding metallic texture) seems inconsistent with the documentation even for the 2017.1 build & may be the result of a bug.

Comment: All right, thanks anyway. I must update it now : )